# How to combine drawn pixels in a UIView with the image in a UIImageView and save it as a new image?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I am wondering how to combine drawn pixels in a UIView with the image in a UIImageView and save it as a new image? I have no clue how to go about this.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would love it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Quartz 2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html). Specifically, `CGContextDrawImage()` can be used to load an image, draw whatever you want on this context, and then you can `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()` to create a `CGImageRef` from which you can create an image with `UIImage`'s `imageWithCGImage`. Finally, you use `UIImagePngRepresentation()` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` to get a NSData that you can then use `writeToFile` with.