# How combine UIImageViews and and save as Single in Gallery as Single Image

Tags: iphone, ios

In my new iPhone Project, I want to combine 5 **UIImageViews** and and save as  Single in Gallery as Single Image.. All that 5 Images in same view Is that possible..?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am trying adding an option to create an Avatar... So i want to join different image views as one... and want to save in gallery

Comment: please provide some snap of your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127363/817946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for combining 2 images into 1, you'll need to tweak it for 5.

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
        UIImage *image = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize); 
    }
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), 
                                        roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), 
                                         roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```